# How to create one corner plot with two sets of data

Tags: python

I am plotting a simple corner plot in python using corner.py:

```
corner(my_data)
```

to produce something like:

[image]

I want to create a corner plot that superimposes `my_data` and `my_other_data` on one corner plot. Is this possible? Or would I have to make my own version of a corner plot rather than using corner.py?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just pass the figure return value of the first corner plot with the `fig` parameter into the second plot:

```
import corner
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ndim, nsamples = 2, 10000
np.random.seed(42)
samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])
figure = corner.corner(samples)
corner.corner(samples * 2, fig=figure, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]